# Tail command - follow by name on Solaris

Tags: filenames, solaris, file-descriptor, tail

Is there a way to tail a file by name on Solaris 10?
Equivalent to:

```
tail --follow=name
```

Manual for tail on solaris shows no such option. Only -f is included and it looks like it follows a file by descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the GNU [`tail` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html), `--follows` is the same as `-f`:

```
-f, --follow[={name|descriptor}]
    output appended data as the file grows;

    an absent option argument means 'descriptor'
```

A `-f` option is found in the POSIX description of [`tail`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html).  However, the `--follows` option (which accepts an option *value*) is not in POSIX.  The GNU manual goes on to describe the `--follow` option where it differs from `-f`:

> With --follow (-f), tail **defaults** to following the file descriptor,
>   which means that even if a tail'ed file is renamed, tail will
>   continue to track its end.  This default behavior is not desirable
>   when you really want to track the actual name of the file, not the
>   file descriptor (e.g., log rotation).  Use **--follow=name** in that
>   case.  That causes tail to track the named file in a way that
>   accommodates renaming, removal and creation.

That is, `--follow` provides for reopening the file if the actual file was renamed.  POSIX does not appear to address this use case.

There is no direct equivalent in Solaris's differences from POSIX (compare `/usr/bin/tail` and `/usr/xpg4/bin/tail` in [manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/tail-1.html#scrolltoc)).

GNU `tail` is part of the [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) package.  You may already have it installed on Solaris 10, in `/opt/sfw/bin/tail`.  For instance, `pkginfo` shows it on my Solaris 10 machine as `SFWcoreu`.

Comment: Solaris 11.2 has GNU `tail` installed in as `/usr/bin/gtail`, from the `file/gnu-coreutils` package.

Comment: OP  asked about Solaris 10.

Comment: Which is why it's in a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris does not have --follow as you see.

The workaround is redirection:

```
tail -f inputfile > filewritten_by_tail
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to install GNU `find` either from [source](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/) or some freeware repository.

If you really want to stick with Solaris 10 bundled `find`, you'll need to wrap it with a custom monitoring program that will restart it should the target file is renewed.

Answer (score -1):

Works like a charm on solaris 11!

`/usr/bin/gtail -F`